# Passing a python list into plpy execute for the in operator without string interpolation

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I have a plpython query for an 'in' where clause

```
    user_ids = [1,2,3]
    query = "SELECT department from users where id in ($1)" 
    prepared_query = plpy.prepare(query, ['bigint'])
        # not sure what the type should be if id is bigint
    plpy.execute(prepared_query, user_ids)
```

The problem is I am unsure what the argument type should be

I get errors for different combinations I have tried:

- When using the above syntax it was throwing an error because of the commas in the list
- when using a bigint[] I got the no operator bigint = bigint[].
- I have tried passing in a comma separated string using ",",join()
- I have cast the list to tuple as well which didn't work

Has anyone got this to work? It's poorly documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem I managed to get this fixed by switching the where clause to `where id = ANY($1)` and using `bigint[]` as the argument type